# Theorem $8.12$ Apostol's Analytic Number Theory?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

The below texts are from the book Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol:

[image]

Suppose $k=7$. Then for $n=7$, $q= \gcd(7,7)=7>1$. So for any $a<7$, $a \equiv 1 \mod 1$ holds since $a-1$ is a multiple of $1$ for any $a$. But $\chi(a) \ne 1$  *for any* $a>1$ as the following table shows:

[image]

So how the theorem is true?

Added; The following is the proof of the above Theorem. I can't find any mistake in it but still don't know how/why $\chi(a)=1$ is inconsistent with the values for $\chi_i(n)$'s.

[image]

Comment: I don't like Apostol's derivation. The only thing you have to know is that Dirichlet characters are [their own (complex conjugate) discrete Fourier transform](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27489/the-discrete-fourier-transform-of-a-dirichlet-charachter/1603965#1603965). This is why Dirichlet L-functions $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ also have a functional equation, as $\zeta(s)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your supposed counterexample $n=k=7$, if $\chi$ is the trivial character, then certainly $\chi(a)=1$ for all $a=1,\dots,6$, and if $\chi$ is a nontrivial character, then we have
$$
G(n,\chi)=\sum_{m=0}^6\chi(m)e^{2\pi i 7m/7}=\sum_{m=1}^6\chi(m)=0,
$$
so the hypothesis that $G(n,\chi)\neq 0$ does not hold, and thus the theorem does not apply.

Comment: Can whoever downvoted this point out what they have an issue with?

Comment: I guessed that the problem should lie in $G(n,\chi)\neq 0$ but I was unable to figure that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :-)